Touch and Facelogin and Screenunlock Surface Book (1)
Since Microsoft will not support my Surface Book anymore, i installed Ubuntu. But I'm missing some important funktionalities:
Touch Screen and pen is not working
The button to unlock the screen from the keyboard ist also not working.
I'm new to Ubunto and Linux and can't find anything helpful online. The LapTop is/was very good, but Microsoft wants that i buy simply a new one. But i simply don't have the money an dont't see a reason.
Can some guide me please?

Check out https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface. Installation instruction found in https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#installation. You device is supported.

You can find more workarounds for your computer in https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#installation

Does this answer your question? Using Ubuntu on Microsoft Surface Book
